# Ошибка ''undefined is not an object (evaluating...)'' в цикле

Tags: javascript

Почему при исполнении выдает ошибку?

```
function findLongestWord(str) {
  let words = str.split(' ');
  let max = 0;
  for (i = 0; i <= words.length; i++){
    if (words[i].length > max){
      max = words[i].length;
    }
  }
  return max;
}

findLongestWord("The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog");
```

Comment: `i < words.length`

Comment: @Igor помогло. Но можете объяснить почему так?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Индекс последнего элемента массива `length - 1`, соответственно, условие, при нарушении которого цикл должен остановиться, `i < words.length` или `i <= words.length - 1`.

```js
function findLongestWord(str) {
  let words = str.split(' ');
  let max = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < words.length; i++){ // !!!
    if (words[i].length > max){
      max = words[i].length;
    }
  }
  return max;
}

console.log(findLongestWord("The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog"));
```